# Necessity of using ObserveOn for Observables?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, system.reactive

See the following code:

```
 var obs = Observable.Start(() => LongRunningMethodToRetrieveData());

 obs.Subscribe(x => MethodThatMustBeOnUIThread(x));
```

If I am certain that these 2 lines of code are executed on the UI thread, is it necessary to first call `ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)`? Or similarly, do I need to check `InvokeRequired` inside of `MethodThatMustBeOnUIThread`?

Basically, am I guaranteed with those 2 lines of code that the 'OnNext' will be called on the thread that is creating the subscription?

Thanks.

Edit: Well, I tried in the debugger and 'MethodThatMustBeOnUIThread' is indeed being called from a background thread. Why is this? My assumption now is that the observing happens by default on the thread that the asynchronous method is run on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get familiar with the default scheduler used by the various Rx methods.

Methods like `Observable.Generate` do run on the thread that subscribes to the observable.

On the other hand, the `Observable.Start` method's purpose is to asynchronously call the lamdba action when the observable is subscribed to. It wouldn't be asynchronous if it happened on the UI-thread. So in this case it uses the `ThreadPool` scheduler.

This can be seen by using Reflector.NET:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Start<TSource>(Func<TSource> function)
{
    if (function == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
    }
    return function.ToAsync<TSource>()();
}

public static Func<IObservable<TResult>> ToAsync<TResult>(
    this Func<TResult> function)
{
    if (function == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("function");
    }
    return function.ToAsync<TResult>(Scheduler.ThreadPool);
}
```

So, knowing the scheduler used you must use a form of `ObserveOn` before calling `Subscribe` if you want the subscription to run on the UI-thread.

Also, since you are using Rx, I wouldn't use `InvokeRequired` - that's just mixing asynchronous coding models. Rx has everything you need to play with threads nicely.